# How to add dynamically changing fields in work items in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am using a custom process.
I have multiple teams in project eg: A , B.
There is a custom field (dropdown) in a Bug work item.
My requirement is that when a user from "Team A" edit the Bug work item, he should only be able to view some of the values in that dropdown, same for the user in Team B .
In summary we need to filter the dropdown values in that custom dropdown list based on the team of a user.

Is this customisation possible in azure devops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add dynamically changing fields in work items in Azure Devops

I am afraid that there is no out of box method to dynamically changing fields in work items in the current processes.

According to the document [Work item fields and attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-fields?view=azure-devops), the `picklistId` property cannot be changed once it has been set:

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right , unfortunately its not possible.